# Return number of tickets created per week with SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of tickets, common_ticket, with a column called creation_date, which holds the date of creation.

I want to count how many tickets were created each week for the past few months. I am having trouble writing a SQL query to return such information. How it is returned is not really important as long as there is a distinct number for each separate week.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT extract(week from creation_date), 
       extract(year from creation_date),
       count(*)
FROM tickets
GROUP BY extract(week from creation_date), 
         extract(year from creation_date)
```

Answer (score 2):

this should do it:

```
SELECT [t1].[value] AS [Year], [t1].[value2] AS [Week], COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM (
    SELECT DATEPART(Year, [t0].[creation_date]) AS [value],
        DATEPART(Week, [t0].[creation_date]) AS [value2]
    FROM [common_ticket] AS [t0]
) AS [t1]
GROUP BY [t1].[value], [t1].[value2];
```

Comment: -1, for illegal PostgreSQL syntax (or any other standard compliant DBMS)

Comment: c'mon "horse", that is perfectly legal TSQL 2008

Comment: Yes, but the question is tagged with PostgreSQL, so your solution is not applicable for the OP (btw: the dreaded brackets are absolutely unnecessary in your query)

Comment: true, maybe not helping 100% the OP, but others searching for "sql" tag will not be all looking for PostgreSQL; as far as the brackets go, I disagree they are "absolutely" unnecessary, they protect against keywords or special chars in the column names, so I prefer to have them for consistency; sorry if those offend you

Comment: If that is your coding convention, this is fine for me. But my personal rule is to avoid quoting (bracket, or standard double quotes) by all means. Using column or table names that need quoting simply beg for problems. And those brackets make the SQL absolutely non-portable (and SQL Server does accept standard quoting as well if I'm not mistaken). Especially if you are targeting other users that search for "sql" you should try to write portable SQL - no Microsoft specific.